# VBA - Targeting immediate text in HTML element

Tags: html, vba, excel

I'm trying to target only the text immediately inside the  element in the following HTML, but the VBA code I'm using is pulling all of the text inside the  elements as well.

```
<a href="/eng/Balance-of-system/Fuse-and-holder/Wohner-31110.000/p/284" id="no-piece">
    90-FT017
    <span class="prod-somm-sepno"></span>
    <span id="panier_fab_284">Wohner</span>
    <span id="panier_nomanufact_284">31110.000</span>
</a>
```

VBA:

```
tdNum = 0
    If document.getElementsByClassName("prod-summ")(tdNum).getElementById("no-piece").innerText = ItemNbr Then
        Cells(cell, 2).Value = document.getElementsByClassName("prod-summ")(tdNum).getElementById("col-action").getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText
    Else
        tdNum = tdNum + 1
    End If
```

`Debug.Print document.getElementById("col-action").getElementsByTagName("span").innerText` shows the result as `90-FT017Wohner 31110.000`

On top of that issue, I'm getting a "Object Variable or With Block Variable not set" error on the first `If` line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each section of text is within a text node, to read `90-FT017` you need to read the text node immediately following the `<a>` element:

```
Document.getElementById("no-piece").FirstChild.nodeValue
```